# Address operator "&" with function returns

Tags: c, gcc, avr

This:

```
bit_is_set(optos(),opt)
```

expanding macro bit_is_set:

```
((*(volatile uint8_t *)(((uint16_t) &(optos())))) & (1 << (opt)))
```

is not working, with error message: lvalue required as unary '&' operand.

But this:

```
uint8_t a=optos();
bit_is_set(a,opt)
```

works fine.

Why?

How do I use the address operator "&" with function returns?

Comment: `optos()` returns a value, not an object. Values have no address.

Comment: `&` is the *address* operator, not the direction operator. You're probably thinking of "direction" as the opposite of "indirection", but that's not common usage.

Comment: ... and excuse me for my bad english!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason why this won't work:

```
uint8_t optos() {
    return 4;
}

int main(void) {
    uint8_t* addr = &optos();
    return 0;
}
```

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

The `&` operand requires an lvalue to return an address. A temporary rvalue (in your case the value returned from `optos()`) can't have its address taken and needs to be bound to a lvalue first.

Comment: Ok.
Casting optos() return's generate or not a temporary lvalue?
Ex: (uint8_t) (optos())

Comment: Won't work, what's the problem in using it as `uint8_t a=optos();` ?

Comment: Any, simply no make explicits variable declarations.  This is all.
Thanks.

Comment: Then change your macro. There's no other way.